# Why is my program trying to use libluajit-5.1.so.2 instead of libluajit.so?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a project I'm writing that uses LuaJIT. I'm trying to run my project on a computer I have not run it on in a while. It used to run just fine but now when I try to run it it complains.

I have LuaJIT in my source tree, and it builds just fine. I'm using CMake to generate my make files, and as far as I can tell CMake finds the file libluajit.so, but when I run my program, I get the following error:

```
../build/game/game: error while loading shared libraries: libluajit-5.1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why it's looking for that version of the library instead of libluajit.so. This is Ubuntu linux for what it's worth. I can add more details if necessary, I can add more details if necessary, I'm not sure what info would be helpful to figure out happening.

Edit:

To build and link the program I have these lines in the file `CMakeLists.txt` (this is abbreviated a bit to just show the relevant bits)

```
find_package(LuaJIT REQUIRED)
set(Extern_LIBS luajit) 
add_executable(proj ${proj_Sources})
target_link_libraries(proj ${Extern_LIBS})
```

After I run cmake on my source directory, I run `make`. Then to run it I just run `./proj`

Comment: How do you link your program? How do you run your program?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Additional info added

Answer (score 1):

When you built it, the ".so" was actually a symlink to the library. Verisioned filenames and [SONAMEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) are used so that multiple versions of a library can coexist, preventing problems commonly found on... other operating systems whereby older software is incompatible with the newer library, and newer software is incompatible with the older library.

Comment: If it was a symlink, running `ls -l` would show that, correct? Running `make` in the luajit directory compiles the .so file right there, it's not a symlink.